# Get Long-Lived Access Token Using Long-Lived Token Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook application using Business Login For Facebook. I have been able to generate a long-lived token for this (which expires in 60 days). I am not sure where to get a long-lived token from this long-lived token. Can somebody point out the right endpoint for that please? I have been unable to find any clues in the documentation.